# Hyperlink column

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm using two textboxes.
One textbox that saves the link to my hyperlink column: http://... and one textbox that saves the description. But i can't get it to work. 
I've tried

```
            new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Links"].ToString()).Url = TextBoxAddLink.Text;
            new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Links"].ToString()).Description = TextBoxLinkDesc.Text;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making two SPFieldUrlValue objects, for one you are setting Url and for other you are setting Description... Instead use below code:

```
  SPFieldUrlValue urlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue();
  urlValue.Url = TextBoxAddLink.Text.Trim();
  urlValue.Description = TextBoxLinkDesc.Text.Trim();

  spListItemObject["UrlField"] = urlValue;
```

This will make a single SPFieldUrlValue object and set both Url and Description properties for a single object, I hope this helps

Comment: I've tried Nadeems answer and it worked. What does trim do?

Comment: Nothing, both the answers are same! Trim we usually use for strings to remove empty spaces from start and end of the string!

Comment: Personally I would prefer @Arsalans answer for the prcise reason that he added Trim. It removes unnecessary spaces. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue();
value.Description = TextBoxLinkDesc.Text;
value.Url = TextBoxAddLink.Text;
item["Links"] = value;
```